# Uploading Image to Server in Next.js 13 results in ENOENT Error

Tags: next.js, next.js13

##### I'm working on a project using Next.js 13 and I'm encountering an issue while trying to upload an image to the server. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
- error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'temp/img.jpeg'
```

## Here's the client side code from my application:

```
"use client";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [name, setname] = useState("rishabh");
  const submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.set("file", file);
    const res = await axios.post("/api/post", formdata);
    console.log(res);
  };

  function sendfile(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    console.log(file);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        <label>upload files</label>
        <input
          name="file"
          onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
          type="file"
        ></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

## Here's the server side code from my application:

```
import { writeFile, writeFileSync } from "fs";
import { NextRequest,NextResponse } from "next/server";
import {join} from 'path';
export async function POST(NextRequest)
{
    const data = await NextRequest.formData();
    const file = data.get('file');
    const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer()
    const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes)
    const path = join('./','temp',file.name)
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log(file.name,buffer);
    console.log('====================================');
    writeFileSync(path,buffer);
    
    return NextResponse.json({message:"get"})
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server-side code, you are constructing the file path using join function for saving the uploaded image. The join function expects its arguments to be path segments that will be concatenated to form a new path. However, you're providing ./ as a path segment, which refers to the current directory, and then appending 'temp' and file.name to it. This results in a concatenated path that starts with ./, making it a relative path from the current working directory. 
You could instead provide an absolute path with process.cwd() to ensure that the path to the file is consistently constructed and is not affected by changes in the working directory. Try something like this,

```js
const fileName = file.name
const path = join(process.cwd(), 'temp', fileName) // Construct absolute path
```

If you are still having issue then you need to ensure that the temp folder exists before you attempt to save files into it. You can use the fs module to create the directory if it doesn't exist,

```js
// Ensure that the 'temp' directory exists
try {
  mkdirSync(join(process.cwd(), 'temp'), { recursive: true })
} catch (error) {
   console.error("Error creating 'temp' directory:", error)
   return NextResponse.json({ error: "An error occurred while creating the directory." }, { status: 500 })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response! I really appreciate your help. I followed your suggestions and made the changes you recommended in my code. The issue seems to be resolved now, and the image upload is working perfectly.